# Android - cannot start new activity, which was started before

Tags: android, android-intent

I cannot solve this problem. I actually don't understand this.
I'm creating a game. One activity, with one level have about 1000 lines of code so I won't be typing it whole. But problem looks like this:
There is some splash activity, which is starting activity, it starts Menu activity and closes itself. Then I open my first level activity [from menu, and I close menu activity by finish()] and when it's finished [this level activity], I want to start another activity. But there problem appears. Everything was working till 3 days ago, right now when I try to open activity it just crashes. I just added few bitmaps to my game if I can remember and edited some lines of code. This fragment in my level is closing it and is suppose to open Menu activity:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(game_over, 0, 0, null);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    soSelCarIgn.release();
                    soSelCarRun.release();
                    Intent menu=new Intent("com.ntii.game.adam.Menu");
                    startActivity(menu);
                    finish();
```

So I try to open activity, which was opened without problem when I was starting the game second ago. It happens with any other activity, except level itself. (I mean, when I try to open level in level then finish() first one, it works). When I'll remove line which is starting activity, level closes itself and everything is ok, without any errors.

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ntii.game.adam.Menu" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

there is this line "android:noHistory="true" because I try any way to close this activity. It gives me errors:
http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/7426/wtfvh.jpg

Bitmaps that I added lately are small size jpegs, what is more I tried to optimize and clean code, removed few other bitmaps, still doesn't work. It looks like this activity is not closing after finish() and when I try to open menu activity, there is not enough memory. Any ideas, clues?

If someone didn't understand this whole activity running order:

SPLASH --> MENU --> LEVEL - TRIES TO OPEN, BUT THERE IS CRASH -> MENU

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Intent menu=new Intent("com.ntii.game.Menu");
```

Use

```
Intent menu=new Intent("com.ntii.game.adam.Menu");
```

OR

```
Intent menu=new Intent(this, com.ntii.game.adam.Menu.class);
```

Comment: Sory, I just modified these fragments to hide my app name and accidentaly removed my name ;) They are the same in my program, but error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent menu = new Intent(currentClass.this, Menu.class);

startActivityForResult(menu,0);
```

The reason being, that the name of the class is "Menu", which is what you want to reference, you don't need the action name, which is : "com.ntii.game.adam.Menu" . ** currentClass just referres to whatever the current class is in your app, since i don't know what it is.

Comment: Well at least you were able to find what was wrong! Sorry I wasn't able to help

Comment: Unfortunetly, it didn't work :( What worked is running splash activity which of course opens menu activity after few seconds. I know this is half-measure, but I don't see any other way now. I'll create just another activity, saying game over, only one picture with XML, run it for 2-3 seconds and it should work. The case is that game itself and menu are created with SurfaceView, propably running menu straight from game takes too much memory and android dont have time to throw game activity so fast, so running XML activity propably gives some time for system to clean memory. Just speculating :)